# Can I set up an OpenVPN server in 12.04 w/o OpenVPN Access Server?

Tags: 12.04, networking, windows-7, macosx, openvpn

Dear AskUbuntu Community Members,

I've got a Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 at my house, not doing much but hosting about three or four printers for my home network. It's  a relatively powerful machine, using a Sandy Bridge Intel processor and in a very well-ventilated location. 
It's connected to a TrendNet router via Ethernet, and I've got one desktop I use for gaming also hooked up via Ethernet. Apart from that, I've got a MacBook Pro I travel with fairly often and an iPhone 5 (not jailbroken). I'd like to set up an OpenVPN server on that Ubuntu machine for all of my machines to hook up to (I travel fairly often), but sadly discovered the hard way that if I opted for the easy path of OpenVPN Access server I'd have to fork out more money than I really want to.

Anyone willing to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `openvpn` package and configure it using the regular documentation. While OpenVPN offers commercial support and services, you can just use the free open source version included in Ubuntu that comes as a package (like the other 50000+ pieces of software in Ubuntu).